# How do I delay the loading of an Image, so that i can display a loading.gif for 2 or 3 seconds before the image loads? (using jQuery/javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have two images:

-loading.gif (which is the loading animation)

-scenery.jpeg (which is i what i want to display after the loading process);

because scenery.jpeg is a small file, using load() function will only skip the loading.gif

so when I click the button how do i display the loading.gif for 3 seconds before it loads scenery.jpeg?

advance thanks! :D

so i have this html file:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#loading , #picture").hide();

    $("#button1").click(function(){
        /* the loading.gif shows then after 3 seconds scenery.jpeg will use fadeIn() */
    });
});
</script>

</head>

<body>
<button id="button1">Click Me!</button>
<img id="loading" src="loading.gif"/>>
<img id="picture" src="scenery.jpeg"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try using `setTimeout`

Comment: Introducing an artificial wait for the user just seems cruel.

Comment: Why do some people think it's a good idea to make their web pages *slower?*

Comment: yeah about setTimeout :| sorry i'm still new to javascript and its functions

how do you use setTimeout function?

Comment: @Blazemonger Bro i'm not thinking of making my web page slower :D haha i just want to study/know about delay functions and stuffs :)

Comment: @itsmejodie yeah! it is :D but for knowledge i just want to know :D how to delay :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [delay()](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) in this case:

```
$("#button1").click(function(){
    $("#loading").fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut('slow', function() {
       $(this).next().fadeIn() 
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5E2nK/)

Comment: hey thanks for the answer:D it works but, can you explain this line?

    $(this).next().fadeIn();

hmmm, how do i specify the next element that will fadeIn?

Comment: @Twish [next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/) help you to find the next sibling of your `loading.gif` image which is `scenery.jpeg` in this case.

Comment: thanks! now i know :D but lastly what if the image is large, then it would take more than 3 seconds to load, how do i prolong the   loading.gif   till   scenery.jpeg loads?

Comment: are you sure it's correct? when i pasted the updated code, nothing appeared on the screen. :)

Comment: @Twish Just ignore my update, I just notice that your image has been already loaded on page load since it's existed in the DOM, so you just need to `show` and `hide` it only.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
$('#loading, #picture').hide();
$('#button1').on('click', function() {
  $('#loading').show();
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#loading, #picture').toggle();
  }, 3000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways would be:

1. Replace image `src` with throbber `src`.
2. Create new `Image` object, set it's `src` to one of image.
3. Add `load` event listener on `Image`, and set img src inside `setTimeout` with desired value.

The function the does that:

```
function delayLoad (img, throbber, delay) {
  var src = img.src,
      hidden = new Image();

  img.src = throbber;

  hidden.addEventListener("load", function (e) {
    setTimeout(function () {
      img.src = src;
    }, delay);
  });

  hidden.src = src;
}
```

Use it like this:

```
delayLoad(document.querySelector("img"), "http://www.mfshop.ru/images/throbber.gif", 3000);
```

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/ENUhUMip/2/edit).